# Timing the life of an object

Tags: java, weak-references

Here is my problem - I want to time how long an object is alive (i.e. on heap) for from a given point (which may be object creation). I don't need to record how long this was at the point of death, just at some point.

My current idea is to create an extension of `WeakReference` that records the start and end time i.e.

```
public class WeakTimeReference extends WeakReference<Object> {

    private final long start;
    private long end = -1;;
    public WeakTimeReference(Object obj, ReferenceQueue<Object> queue){
        super(obj,queue);
        long = System.currentTimeMillis();      
    }

    public Long getLife(){ return (end == -1) ? null : end-start; }

}
```

And then add these to a `WeakHashMap` (so I can tell when I've already created a reference) i.e.

```
private Map<Object,WeakTimeReference> map = 
                   new WeakHashMap<Object,WeakTimeReference>();
private ReferenceQueue queue = new ReferenceQueue();
public void add(Object o){
    if(!map.containsKey(o))
        map.put(o,new WeakTimeReference(o,queue));
}
```

Then when I want to know the times I just look at `queue` i.e.

```
while(queue.poll()){
   WeakTimeReference ref = (WeakTimeReference) queue.remove();
   // do something with ref.getLife()
}
```

However, the issue is that I'm not sure how I would go about getting `end` set in a `WeakTimeReference`. There is no method to override in `Reference` that gets called when it is enqueued, or any such method in `ReferenceQueue`.

My only thought is that I could wrap up objects with a class that has a `finalize` method that does this for me and put these in a `WeakHashMap` pointed to by their wrapped object. But this seems very messy.

So my question is:

Is anyway to perform an action when a reference object gets placed on a reference queue?

Failing that, can anybody see a neater way for me to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you need this? A garbage collected language is supposed to insulate you from this.

Comment: I'm doing research to understand the effects of garbage collection on something else, so want to build up an idea of how long certain objects are alive for. But I don't want to have to go inside the JVM.

Comment: In which case, using the finalizer is probably the best approach. But for research purposes only. And there's no guarantee it will be consistent across JVMs.

Answer (score 2):

Use a finalizer, but you *must* adhere to this pattern:

```
protected void finalize() throws Throwable
{
  try
  {
    // your code here
  }
  finally
  {
    super.finalize();
  }
}
```

or you'll get as close to undefined behaviour as you can with Java.

Answer (score 1):

Use a wrapper with callback handler which will notifiy an Observer when the object is GCed.

```
class Wrapper implements ObjectInterface {
   Object obj;
   Statistics statisics;
   long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis;
   ...
   protected finalize() {
      statisics.notify(obj, System.currentTimeMillis - t0);
   }
}
```

I think Spring AOP would work well for this task